# ASP.NET MVC add translation in multiplanguage from screen/UI dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]In my website -- Add screen/UI from which user can add translation dynamically

for example:

I want to add translation for "Hello World!" in multiple language and want to fetch according to language selection

**Key :**
strHelloWorld

**Value:**
Hello World!

**Language:**
en   (it can be anything english,spanish,german etc)

This above 3 field data we can add/enter from Scree/UI by superadmin and
store/save in whatever form is good it can be in database or in json file

Please suggest way to add translation from screen

Comment: You can use Google translate API.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-multiple-languages-in-asp-net-mvc-4-5-framework/ have a look on the above link  and basically we save it in resx file.

Comment: @ArvindMaurya I want to add translation dynamically from screen without adding rebuild my code

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net has a special file called resource files (.resx) to define the default locale (English) and other language texts.

For that please follow the steps:

- step 1: You need to create **.resx(resource file)** into Resource(new
  folder). create the file for the default language and second file with other lang.
- step 2: set access modifier to **public** otherwise the
  variable value will not appear on the view side
- step 3: enter the variable name in the same in both files but make value different related to language.
- step 4: once you declare the same variable name in both languages resource file, you can use that variable name where ever you want to declare in .cshtml file.

> **ex. Resources.Global.APP_NAME**

**For reference :**
http://www.codedigest.com/posts/53/create-multi-language-website-in-aspnet-mvc---localization

Comment: Can the user change the resx translations at runtime? What if the keyes are dynamic as well?

Comment: Hi @ShimmyWeitzhandler, We can not dynamically change the resx file, but for dynamic change you need to use static words only which are predefined in resx file. by that way you can handled the dyamic functionality.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up storing them all in database.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below nuget package 
It is really awesome thanks to nuget and their author

https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.Globalization

Please note that In this solution they have provided solution for all .net framwork/platform like asp.net 4.5 also aspnet core

Thanks again